# Xamarin.Forms Infinite Scrolling Image Background Effect

Tags: c#, performance, user-interface, animation, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to make what I think will be a nice effect for an app - a series of images (think wallpaper) will be constantly scrolling in the background during a view. I started prototyping this in Xamarin.Forms, creating a custom control. Planned on a diagonal translation but started with the most basic approach and still ran into some issues fairly quickly, namely that it is not entirely smooth as it gets a bit choppy here and there (even when using caching and just a 10kb image) and 2) if user executes an action that's more involved it may cause a lag and the images get rendered more closely together than they should be. Is there a way to fix up this approach so that it's as smooth as possible and doesn't interfere (or get interfered with) the other UI elements, or is there a far superior approach for something like this - anyone ever tackle this? Please let me know, thanks.

**FlyingImageBackground.cs**

```
public class FlyingImageBackground : ContentView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty FlyingImageProperty =
      BindableProperty.Create(nameof(FlyingImage), typeof(ImageSource), typeof(FlyingImageBackground), default(ImageSource), BindingMode.TwoWay, propertyChanged: OnFlyingImageChanged);

    public ImageSource FlyingImage
    {
        get => (ImageSource)GetValue(FlyingImageProperty);
        set => SetValue(FlyingImageProperty, value);
    }

    private AbsoluteLayout canvas;

    public FlyingImageBackground()
    {
        this.canvas = new AbsoluteLayout()
            {
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
            };

        this.canvas.SizeChanged += Canvas_SizeChanged;

        Content = this.canvas;
    }

    ~FlyingImageBackground() => this.canvas.SizeChanged -= Canvas_SizeChanged;

    private static void OnFlyingImageChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var control = (FlyingImageBackground)bindable;
        control.BringToLife();
    }

    private void BringToLife()
    {
        if (this.canvas.Width <= 0 || this.canvas.Height <= 0)
            return;

        Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), () =>
        {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
            {
                await SendImageWave();
            });

            return this.canvas.IsVisible;
        });
    }

    private async Task SendImageWave()
    {
        var startingX = -100;
        var endingX = this.canvas.Width;

        if (endingX <= 0)
            return;

        endingX += 100;

        var yPositions = Enumerable.Range(0, (int)this.canvas.Height).Where(x => x % 90 == 0).ToList();

        var imgList = new List<CachedImage>();

        foreach (var yPos in yPositions)
        {
            var img = new CachedImage
            {
                Source = FlyingImage,
                HeightRequest = 50
            };
            imgList.Add(img);

            this.canvas.Children.Add(img, new Point(startingX, yPos));
        }

        await Task.WhenAll(
            imgList.Select(x => x.TranslateTo(endingX, 0, 10000)));
        //.Concat(imgList.Select(x => x.TranslateTo(startingX, 0, uint.MinValue))));

        imgList.ForEach(x =>
        {
            this.canvas.Children.Remove(x);
            x = null;
        });

        imgList = null;
    }

    private void Canvas_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BringToLife();
    }
}
```

**Usage example:**

Just put it into a Grid in a ContentPage along with the main content:
e.g.:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <Grid>
        <controls:FlyingImageBackground FlyingImage="fireTruck.png" />

        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center">
            <Button
                Text="I'm a button!" />
            <Label
                FontAttributes="Bold,Italic"
                Text="You're a good man, old sport!!!"
                TextDecorations="Underline" />
        </StackLayout>
    </Grid>

</ContentPage.Content>
```

Comment: Just a suggestion : The animation may look good, but think it from the perspective of a user & the device. The device, if it has to load a lot of images, it will first load them into memory(you want performance, right?). Plus, it needs to animate them. This will eat up some good amount of memory, heat up the phone/decrease performance. Remember, a great app is not where you cannot add more features, a great app is one from which you cannot take out the existing features, because they are NEEDED. One thing you can do is, instead of animated too many images, create a gif like so & just use that.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Aousafrashid - yep I totally get that, but in this case 1) I am only using around 50 instances of the same cached image at a given time, 2) would have been convenient to change the image via the binding (this was the point of my original concept, e.g. user changes a certain setting and then the images flying in the background seamlessly transition to a different one, 3) most devices are capable of running pretty decent 3D games - this is a very basic animation with very small-sized assets, I'm hoping to get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switched to SkiaSharp and much better results. The animation appears smooth and if the flow gets interrupted the images maintain their appropriate distance. Also realized in the first draft using the built-in Xamarin Animations that I screwed up the check for when to run it; .IsVisible prop will remain true even if the page isn't even on the screen anymore, so in this new version needed to bind to a property that tells me if the page is actually active or not (based on when it gets navigated to and navigated away from) and if not then stop the animation. This is still just handling the horizontal scrolling effect for now. Hope someone else finds it useful, and any other improvements would be welcome, please just comment/post an answer!

```
[DesignTimeVisible(true)]
public class FlyingImageBackgroundSkia : ContentView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty IsActiveProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(
            nameof(IsActive),
            typeof(bool),
            typeof(FlyingImageBackground),
            default(bool),
            BindingMode.TwoWay,
            propertyChanged: OnPageActivenessChanged);

    private SKCanvasView canvasView;
    private SKBitmap resourceBitmap;
    private Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

    // consider making these bindable props
    private float percentComplete;
    private float imageSize = 40;
    private float columnSpacing = 100;
    private float rowSpacing = 100;
    private float framesPerSecond = 60;
    private float cycleTime = 1; // in seconds, for a single column

    public FlyingImageBackgroundSkia()
    {
        this.canvasView = new SKCanvasView();
        this.canvasView.PaintSurface += OnCanvasViewPaintSurface;
        this.Content = this.canvasView;

        string resourceID = "XamarinTestProject.Resources.Images.fireTruck.png";
        Assembly assembly = GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly;

        using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceID))
        {
            this.resourceBitmap = SKBitmap.Decode(stream);
        }
    }

    ~FlyingImageBackgroundSkia() => this.resourceBitmap.Dispose();

    public bool IsActive
    {
        get => (bool)GetValue(IsActiveProperty);
        set => SetValue(IsActiveProperty, value);
    }

    private static async void OnPageActivenessChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var control = (FlyingImageBackgroundSkia)bindable;
        await control.AnimationLoop();
    }

    private async Task AnimationLoop()
    {
        this.stopwatch.Start();

        while (IsActive)
        {
            this.percentComplete = (float)(this.stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds % this.cycleTime) / this.cycleTime; // always between 0 and 1
            this.canvasView.InvalidateSurface(); // trigger redraw
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0 / this.framesPerSecond)); // non-blocking
        }

        this.stopwatch.Stop();
    }

    private void OnCanvasViewPaintSurface(object sender, SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs args)
    {
        SKImageInfo info = args.Info;
        SKSurface surface = args.Surface;
        SKCanvas canvas = surface.Canvas;

        canvas.Clear();

        var xPositions = Enumerable.Range(0, info.Width + (int)this.columnSpacing).Where(x => x % (int)this.columnSpacing == 0).ToList();
        xPositions.Insert(0, -(int)this.columnSpacing);

        var yPositions = Enumerable.Range(0, info.Height + (int)this.rowSpacing).Where(x => x % (int)this.rowSpacing == 0).ToList();
        yPositions.Insert(0, -(int)this.rowSpacing);

        if (this.resourceBitmap != null)
        {
            foreach (var xPos in xPositions)
            {
                var xPosNow = xPos + (this.rowSpacing * this.percentComplete);
                foreach (var yPos in yPositions)
                {
                    canvas.DrawBitmap(
                        this.resourceBitmap,
                        new SKRect(xPosNow, yPos, xPosNow + this.imageSize, yPos + this.imageSize));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```